# New TF300 is not showing anything on the screen

Tags: screen, asus-eee-pad-transformer

I purchased an [ASUS TF300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007P4YAPK) from Amazon and it arrived today. The manual says to charge it for 8 hours for optimal battery life, so I plugged it in and let it charge for a bit. The power button is now displaying a green light after about two hours of charging (it's still plugged in), and when I press the button the tablet's backlight comes on. However, the screen is blank - nothing is being displayed.

I've tried forcing a reboot (holding the power button down for 8 seconds). The tablet makes a chiming noise and appears to reboot - based on the backlight turning off and then back on - but there is still nothing displayed on the screen.

Any suggestions? Is it possible it's DOA?

Comment: The manual actually says that? Bunch of idiots there.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik "To prolong battery life, fully charge the battery for up to 8 hours when using the ASUS Transformer Pad for the first time and whenever the battery power is fully depleted." :) Seemed a little off to me as well, which is why I just gave it a shot after it got a few hours of charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to resolve the issue through all types of hard/cold resets/reboots (PWR+VOL, PWR for 30 seconds, hard reset pin, etc), so I returned to Amazon and received a working tablet today. It appears that mine was just DOA.